# String Anagrams in a Running Stream

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

You have a continuous stream of strings. At any point of time, you have to print the strings such that those which are permutations of one another are printed together.

For example:

Input: {‘act’,’cat’,dog’,’tac’,’abc’,’god’,’bac’}

Output: {‘act’,’cat’,’tac’   ,dog’,’god’   ,’abc’,’bac’}

More words can be added.

Which algorithm  or data structure can be used?

Comment: It's completely unclear to me when a particular string needs to be output.

Comment: we have to divide the given strings into groups basically: For example cat ,act and tac will be in one groups because all these three strings are permutation of one another,Similarly dog and god are anagrams so they will be in another group.

Comment: Much clearer.  Also can e.g. 'dog' and 'god' appear at the start?  At the end?  In reverse order?  Please update your question with answers to all these things.

Comment: As of now,you can print them in any order,at the start end or anywhere ,but this is running stream,more words can be added

Comment: Don't use the word "stream" because it has a specific meaning that does not apply here.  Stream algorithms always read just the next small piece of the input before writing the next small piece of the output. That approach doesn't work here, since we can't write the next word until we have seen *all* input words.

Answer (score 2):

If you like C++, then simply store them like this:

```
unordered_map<string, vector<string> > anagrams;
void insert(const string& str) {
    string copy = str;
    sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    anagrams[str].push_back(copy);
}
```

anagrams form an equivalence classes by the lexicographically smallest string that can be obtained from a permutation of all the characters. You can also come up with a bunch of other equivalence class formulations.

I guess printing should be obvious.

Comment: :Can you please give a small example